# Tic Tac Toe best possible move

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

i just finished making an algorithm that determines the best move to play in a tic ta toe

```
 def best_Move(self,grid):
  valMax = -2
  posMax = None
  for i in range(9):
    if  grid[i] == ".":
        val = self.move_value(grid[i])
        if val > valMax:
            valMax = val
            posMax = i



return posMax
```

and

```
def move_value(self,position):

    self.grid[position]=player

    if self.won(grid) == "x" or self.win(grid) == "o":
        val = +1
    elif len(grid) == 9:
        val = 0
    else:
        player=change_player(player)
        val=-self.move_value(self.best_move(grid))
        player=change_player(player)

    self.grid[position]="."


    return val
```

the method best_move returns the index of the best move 
and the method move_value returns : 0 if it's a tie or 1 if the player who played won when he played at that specific position or -1 if the player who just played lost when he played at that specific position

the method change_player(player) changes the player from x to o or from o to x 
and the method won checks if there is a winner and if so it returns it's sign (x or o)

the problem is that sometimes it works (which means it gives me the best possible move ) and sometimes it doesn't 
here's an example where it just doesn't work 
grid=["x",".",".","o","x",".",".",".","."]

### x . .

### o  x .

### .  .  .

the result that it return is 1 while it should be 8

i hope you guys can help me out with this

Comment: I've written a TicTacToe AI in Python 3. You can check here https://github.com/houluy/TicTacToe

Comment: hello , i just saw your tic tac toe code it's really good however i didn't really get how you generated the best move to be played by the ai player

Comment: First, give each position a number to evaluate the priority, then, set out some rules to modify the priority. For example, if the next step makes a line, the number adds 10, if it cannot make a line but block up the opponent, the number adds 5, if the pos does nothing useful, the number adds 1. Finally, choose the pos with the highest priority.  Anyway, if you use machine learning algorithms such as Q-learning to solve this problem, your AI may be more intelligent.